# Write to resource file java?

Tags: java, maven, file, resources

I'm trying to dynamically write data to a resource file in java but I can't seem to succeed. Is it possible at all? I tried a few approaches but none of them worked.

I have a main method which represents:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    ClassLoader loader = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
    File file = new File(loader.getResource("authors/authors.log").getFile());

    FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file);
    System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());

    writer.write("Test test \n");

    writer.flush();

    System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());

    writer.write("Test 2");

    writer.flush();
    writer.close();

}
```

After executing the main method an exception isn't thrown but the authors.log file doesn't seem to be changed and no data is written.

Files are :

> src/main/java/main/Main.java
>
> src/main/resource/authors/authors.log
>
> target/classes/authors/authors.log

However the target directory contains an `authors.log` file and all the data is written there. 
Am I wrong somewhere or just java doesn't allow writing to a resource file ?
If so where is the best place to store files which are changed by the program (e.g. log files)

Comment: According to the content of `target`, your resource directory is correct and so should be `src/main/resources` and not `src/main/resource` as stated in your question.

Answer (score 3):

> However the target directory contains an authors.log file and all the
>   data is written there.

It is rather expected as it is the file that you opened and modified.

The following statement uses the classloader to retrieve the file and not the filesystem :

```
File file = new File(loader.getResource("authors/authors.log").getFile());
```

So it will retrieve the file located in `target/classes` and not which one located in `src/main/resources`.

Use the filesystem by specifying the relative path of the current working directory to be able to change the content of  `src/main/resources` :

For example :

```
File file = new File("src/main/resources/authors/authors.log");
```

or better with the `java.nio` API :

```
Path file = Paths.get("src/main/resources/authors/authors.log");
```

---

> If so where is the best place to store files which are changed by the
>   program (e.g. log files)

Beyond the technical question, you should wonder why your application needs to modify the source code.  It should be done only in very specific corner cases.
For example, the log files don't have to be located in the source code, these have to be outside the source code project because these don't make part of the application source code and are not tools to build the application either.

Comment: Unrelated: I came across https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51383166/hdr-an-image-in-java ... and close voted ... now it is re-opened, and I am kinda wondering about my assessment. What do you think, is that question now asking for a library recommendation (and should be closed as such), or fine as it is now?

Comment: Hey :) If it was closed by the community and that it was then reopened by the community, it is probably because the question is at the boundaries of the validity/invalidity for a question on SO.  Considering as a request for a library is acceptable. But personally, I consider it just too broad (as stated by a comment).  Now as the OP question is complex enough I think I would forgive the broadness and would let the question open. It is just my mind.